# Protractor fails with multiCapabilities but passes when only one test runs

Tags: angularjs, protractor, gulp-protractor

I am having an issue running a test with 'multiCapabilities'. My multiCapabilities config is:

```
   multiCapabilities: [{
    browserName: 'chrome',
    'name': 'LMB Decision Engine - UI Automation',
    'tunnel-identifier': 'nonprod',
    'parent-tunnel': 'LMSauceLabs'
  }, {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    'name': 'LMB Decision Engine - UI Automation',
    'tunnel-identifier': 'nonprod',
    'parent-tunnel': 'LMSauceLabs'
  }],
```

And the response that I get is:

```
[chrome #2]     Failed: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
[chrome #2]       (Session info: chrome=47.0.2526.73)
[chrome #2]       (Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353141 (da3cb4b52d3a04ce079546eac4dc96182f58602b),platform=Linux 3.13.0-32-generic x86)
```

However, when I run with this capabilities config it passes:

```
  capabilities : {
    'browserName': 'firefox',
    'name': 'LMB Decision Engine - UI Automation',
    'tunnel-identifier': 'nonprod',
    'parent-tunnel': 'LMSauceLabs'
  },
```

Has anyone seen this issue when running in parallel? I've tried all different combinations of browser, and disabling all of the plugins individually to see if they are incompatible with multiCapabilities, but the issue seems to be solely running in parallel version individually.

Thanks,
Tyler

Comment: I remember some time ago we had running our tests in parallel without chrome, and ran the chrome tests separately (don't remember why). Does this issue persist with parallel firefox tests?

Comment: This is failing for all different browser combos. Tried Firefox/Chrome again and it still failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to run parallel tests in chrome you could use shardTestFiles:true in the multi capabilities config, like this:

```
multiCapabilities: [
    {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    shardTestFiles: true, 
     // change this to the number of instances you want to run
    maxInstances:2
}];
```